# application cannot be installed in the default install location?

Tags: applications, installation

I have an Android Galaxy S1, and have been getting the error "application cannot be installed in the default install location". I am aware that this is a common issue. So I Googled it, and almost everyone is saying to move your apps to the SD card or delete unused games.

There's only one problem. My phone won't let me move apps into the SD card, and I have 1.3GB of free app space. While I can download some apps, the more important ones won't download.

Anyone have any fixes to this?

Comment: You cannot! Some require to be on internal storage, read *non-moveable to external storage* for the app to work, widgets is one example.

Comment: So there's no way to fix the "application cannot be installed in the default install location?" error without moving apps to SDCard, is what you're saying?

Comment: It depends on apps that are required to be on internal storage, facebook, google mail, play store, to name but a few are ones that are on internal storage only, i.e. default install location! :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, what i did is uninstall some unused app & then reboot my device. Now, after it my device is working charm... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this really has anything to do with any settings.

I encountered this yesterday. All I did was restart my phone and the app installed fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Developers can define the [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) in their app's `Manifest` file. As you stated you cannot move apps to your SDCard, this might be the clue: Apps having their install location set to the internal storage will be able to install, while those defined for external storage (i.e. SDCard) are failing for the very same reason: They cannot be moved to the SDCard.

So your real problem is: Why can't you move apps to the SDCard? To find an answer to this, it would also be helpful to know your Android version. I'd suggest making this a separate question linking here, and giving some more details on your device and Android version there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

If the settings-> memory is set to SD card then change it to Internal, or visa versa.

Unmount the SD card.

Install/update

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue, removed some really large apps off the phone and it installed fine. Guess it was a space issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have android 4.1.1 what I did to fix the issue about installing to default install location.... Go to settings ....then to storage....then the preferred install location....then select let the system decide 
That's it . U can always change it back to sd card when u finish updating the apps with the issue